# sentiment analysis using aws fails because the cloudformation stack doesn't seem to find my source code s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

from last couple of days we have been working on a sentiment analysis project using aws. we have used this  ( https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/ai-driven-social-media-dashboard/ ) reference material to work on our cloudformation template. While using our custom template , the cloudformation stack doesn't seem to find our source code s3 bucket.

Comment: Could you provide us with some kind of logs or at least some more information?

Comment: @RobertKossendey,
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EYaBYO7qeREpgl5Lw2hyXidKOXVQkM5t/view?usp=sharing
here is an image to the exact problem. also, I don't know how I can view the logs in cloudformation ???

Comment: Can you provide your template.yaml as well?

Comment: @RobertKossendey,
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ogSpxuIW1QCT0BssoN5VbKbztY6O8BW2/view?usp=sharing . Made some changes in my template.yml , if you have a look at the reference material , their source code has template.yml which is quite similiar.
Their Github Repo:https://github.com/amazon-archives/ai-driven-social-media-dashboard

Comment: Try to remove the single quotes from the bucket name when referencing it -> !Ref TweetsBucket

Comment: @RobertKossendey, I am unable to find Bucket Name where single quotes are used, maybe if you could tell me the line-no???

Comment: Nevermind, the problem lies somewhere else. The problem is in line 476. Does the bucket with your code exist?

Comment: hey @RobertKossendey, just wanted to reach out to say thanks for your help and I might have found some lead from one of my friends. I would be glad if we could connect , here is my linkedin:https://www.linkedin.com/in/adit-modi-2a4362191/

Comment: for anyone facing a similar issue, the solution is in this link.https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler/issues/115

Comment: @RobertKossendey, I seem to be working on it, cloudformation stack seems to find the s3 bucket but the ec2 instance doesn't seem to scrape twitter data. i.e the node api in ec2 twitter code doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is creating two buckets.
One by the name s3-bucket ( bucket-name)
another by the name s3-bucket-us-east-1 ( bucket-name-attached-with-region-name)
place the /dist folder containing your cloudformation template in both this buckets and the error is resolved.